# Git feature branch changes being carried over to master

Tags: git

Locally I made a new feature branch following with a few changes.

```
git checkout -b feature_branch
```

I switched back to master and found that those changes to my feature branch were carried over to master. In past projects any changes from either my master or feature branches were completely agnostic of one another. What could I have done wrong in the setup process for this to occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you commit your work before returning to the master branch?

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Commit description"
```

If you didn't, your changes would still be in your working directory.
You can check this with `git status`, and if you need to you can rectify the situation by checking out your branch again and committing.

Comment: So hypothetically would I need to add and commit in the feature branch before going back to master or another branch for that matter?

Comment: Yes, uncomitted changes don't belong to any branch.